# Add Drop Down menu on clicking an svg element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm making front-end for flow chart builder where in I am using SVG for drawing elements. I want to click an SVG element (specifically, svg rect) to show a drop-down menu saying -
"Edit" and "Delete".

On clicking Edit, I want it to open a pop-up form to fill details to create a new rectangle connecting via arrow. 
How to set on-click events for the svg elements and how to include the drop down menu further?

I have already made the shape and svg elements. However, I am not able to set any on-click event onto that.

```html
<svg width="400" height="180">
 <rect x="60" y="40" width="150" height="50" 
style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(51,23,163);stroke-width:3;fill- 
opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
 <text x="85" y="61" font-family="Calibri" font-size="14" 
fill="black">Click to edit first</text>
 <text x="92" y="77" font-family="Calibri" font-size="14" 
fill="black">decision node</text>
</svg>
```

Here is how it looks now: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_rect2

I want this rectangle to be able to show two options to click on and then expand to form a new rectangle

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to events on svg elements just like on any other:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
svg.addEventListener('click', () => {console.log('clicked')});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg id='svg' width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;fill-opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
 <script>
 const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
 svg.addEventListener('click', event => {console.log('clicked', event)});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After clicking the element with id `svg` you should see message in console with an event object next to it. That object does have properties that can be useful for you to display pop-up (eg. in `event.target` you have information about clicked element such as its positon).

As far as pop-up is concerned you could go with creating a form in HTML and toggle its visibility with adding/removing CSS class:

```
const svg = document.getElementById('svg');
const form = document.getElementById('form');
svg.addEventListener('click', event => {
    form.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: But how do I add that click event specifically for the rectangle only and not the complete svg tag?

Comment: The code I've written in fact targets element by its id - I just named it `svg` but it can be anything: ```<svg id='myRect' width="400" height="180">``` and then in JS: ```const svg = document.getElementById('myRect');```

Comment: Oh right. But, I am adding those two lines of code under <script>. However, it is not working. Could you maybe write the exact thing or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery would be good.

```js
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(){
alert('clicked');

// add your pop up form
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="180">
 <rect class="clickMe" x="60" y="40" width="150" height="50" 
style="fill:white;stroke:rgb(51,23,163);stroke-width:3;fill- 
opacity:0.1;stroke-opacity:0.9" />
 <text class="clickMe" x="85" y="61" font-family="Calibri" font-size="14" 
fill="black">Click to edit first</text>
 <text class="clickMe" x="92" y="77" font-family="Calibri" font-size="14" 
fill="black">decision node</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: The snippet is working over here. But the same is not working when I'm trying to do the same

Comment: Can you help me out on if there is any additional things that needs to be added?

Comment: Have you added jquery? check your console whether jquery is loaded. Also you need to add classes as shown in the answer

Comment: If you dont want to use jquery, then check this pen https://codepen.io/soothran/full/mNbqbj.